# Eclipse not exporting latest version as runnable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Simple as that - my eclipse (<s>Mars Release (4.5.0)</s> EDIT: **Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)**), when exporting a runnable JAR using the correct run configuration, keeps releasing a version of one of my classes as a version approximately 2 days old instead of the latest. I noticed as the functionality has changed rather drastically, yet the JAR keeps acting the same.

Yes I'm definitely overwriting the previous version.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)?

Comment: Just updated, yes same issue.

Comment: Can you provide some more information to reproduce your issue, for instance: What kind of project is it (plain Java, Maven, Gradle, ...)? Where is the class that contains the main method located (in the `src` folder, in a JAR, in both)? Is the `bin` folder under version control by mistake? etc.

Comment: Absolutely:

What kind of project is it?
-Pure Java, no Maven or Gradle.
Where is the class that contains the main method located?
-In the SRC folder, in a package named "Test".
Is the `bin` folder under version control by mistake?
-No, and the project runs fine within Eclipse. Only the runnable JAR has the issue of being an old version.

Thanks for your assistance and time.

Comment: Ok I replaced the main class with a system out statement and it's still running the previous code. This is after deleting the previous JAR, then writing the new JAR to the same directory. It's definitely not outputting the correct JAR. I thought this might be a run configuration issue when selecting from the JAR run configuration, but I cleared that and it still failed. T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is a known bug, as reported on the Eclipse forums here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525711

Here is the full answer:

> The easiest workaround at the current moment is to use an older
>   version of the jdk for eclipse. This can be done by going into
>   Window->Preferences->Java->Install JREs and adding the older jdk
>   folder.
>
> I've rolled back to jdk8 and the eclipse's export jar works fine, in
>   most cases.
>
> If you really need to use Java9, then you're best bet is to manually
>   create the jar using javac or using another build system like Gradle.

Comment: [This bug has already been fixed in Oxygen.2](https://youtu.be/_EY1eeQtY_U?t=48s). And how were you able to use Mars with Java 9?